# Elasticsearch does not work with Wagtail 1.7 and SSL active

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, wagtail

I can't run ElasticSearch 2 with Wagtail 1.7 and with https connections. Do I need to add anything else to the settings of elasticSearch in the django / Wagtail settings? Or in the configuration of elasticsearch2 (`elasticsearch.yml`) itself?

Thanks in advance.

(EDIT): I have this error when i run `./manage.py update_index`:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.SSLError: ConnectionError([SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:645)) caused by: SSLError([SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:645))

My elastic settings are:

```
 WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'wagtail.wagtailsearch.backends.elasticsearch2',
            'URLS': ['https://www.santanderconsumerbank.be'],
            'AUTO_UPDATE': False,
            'ATOMIC_REBUILD': True,
            'INDEX': 'santander-consumer-benelux',
            'TIMEOUT':5,
        },
    }
```

Comment: Please can you describe the specific problem you're encountering - any error messages, for example?

Comment: Edited with the error message

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by an invalid SSL certificate.

Since v1.5, Wagtail [defaults to verifying SSL certs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/releases/1.5.html?highlight=ssl#elasticsearch-backend-now-defaults-to-verifying-ssl-certs). As such, you need to add your following to the backends config:

```
    'OPTIONS': {
      'use_ssl': True,
      'verify_certs': False,
    }
```

See http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/topics/search/backends.html#elasticsearch-backend.

Last, but not least, do check that your ES URL is the correct one.